# reading and parsing nested XML tags and save to CSV using Python, Unable to read the nested tag

Tags: python, xml, csv, elementtree, xml.etree

I've looked and tried multiple things however have not been able to read the nested tags in my XML file. I have extracted the outter tags value and not the nested street and city tags under the address tag. I'm on a time crunch and I'm unable to read the nested tags after trying a bunch of things. PLEASE HELP!!!

The expected outcome I'm trying to get it is ---->

Common    Botanical  zone    light   price  Street  City

bloodroot Sanguinaria canadensis  4 mostly shady  2.44   1  toronto

And so on ---->

However, I have not been able to retrieve the street and city columns because my code is not picking up the nested  tags.

I have been able to achieve the following output by removing the code involving city and street tags.

Common        Botanical           zone    light       price
bloodroot Sanguinaria canadensis   4    mostly shady  2.44

The following is my xml file with 2 entries only for testing purposes. I'm trying to create columns of each text information under the plant tag also mentioned above. I'm reading using the databricks file system. I open and create a csv and write to it and then close it. The indentation is correct, it may have been mixed up when I was copy pasting.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<CATALOG>

  <PLANT>

    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>

    <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>

    <ZONE>4</ZONE>

    <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>

    <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>

    <ADDRESS>

         <STREET>1</STREET>

         <CITY>toronto</CITY>

    </ADDRESS>

    <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>

  </PLANT>

  <PLANT>

    <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>

    <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>

    <ZONE>3</ZONE>

    <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>

    <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>

    <ADDRESS>

         <STREET>2</STREET>

         <CITY>montreal</CITY>

    </ADDRESS>

    <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>

  </PLANT>

</CATALOG>


-----------This is the code I have used ---------------
from xml.etree import ElementTree

import csv

import os


xml = ElementTree.parse("/dbfs/mnt/ods-outbound/xml_test/plant_catalog.xml")

#creating a file

csvfile= open("/dbfs/mnt/ods-outbound/xml_test/plant_catalog.csv",'w',encoding='utf-8')

csvfile_writer=csv.writer(csvfile)

# ADD THE HEADER TO CSV FILE

csvfile_writer.writerow(["common","botanical","zone","light","price","availability","street","city"])

# FOR EACH PLANT

for plant in xml.findall("PLANT"):
    if(plant)

      # EXTRACT PLANT DETAILS 

      common = plant.find("COMMON")

      botanical = plant.find("BOTANICAL")

      zone = plant.find("ZONE")

      light = plant.find("LIGHT")

      price = plant.find("PRICE")

      availability = plant.find("AVAILABILITY")

      street = plant.find("STREET")

      city = plant.find("CITY")

      csv_line = [common.text, botanical.text, zone.text, light.text, price.text, availability.text,street.text,city.text]

      # ADD A NEW ROW TO CSV FILE

      csvfile_writer.writerow(csv_line)

csvfile.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As per the xml file, the street and city values are inside address tag.

`changes` :

- Find the address tag in page
- if address tag then find street and city

`a.xml` (input file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<CATALOG>
  <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Bloodroot</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Sanguinaria canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>4</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>$2.44</PRICE>
    <ADDRESS>
         <STREET>1</STREET>
         <CITY>toronto</CITY>
    </ADDRESS>
    <AVAILABILITY>031599</AVAILABILITY>
  </PLANT>
  <PLANT>
    <COMMON>Columbine</COMMON>
    <BOTANICAL>Aquilegia canadensis</BOTANICAL>
    <ZONE>3</ZONE>
    <LIGHT>Mostly Shady</LIGHT>
    <PRICE>$9.37</PRICE>
    <ADDRESS>
         <STREET>2</STREET>
         <CITY>montreal</CITY>
    </ADDRESS>
    <AVAILABILITY>030699</AVAILABILITY>
  </PLANT>
</CATALOG>
```

`main.py` :

```
import csv
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.parse("a.xml")

csvfile= open("plant_catalog.csv",'w',encoding='utf-8',newline="")
csvfile_writer=csv.writer(csvfile)
csvfile_writer.writerow(["common","botanical","zone","light","price","availability","street","city"])

for plant in xml.findall("PLANT"):
    if(plant):
      common = plant.find("COMMON").text
      botanical = plant.find("BOTANICAL").text
      zone = plant.find("ZONE").text
      light = plant.find("LIGHT").text
      price = plant.find("PRICE").text
      availability = plant.find("AVAILABILITY").text
      for addr in plant.findall("ADDRESS"):
        if(addr):
          street = addr.find("STREET").text
          city = addr.find("CITY").text
      csv_line = [common, botanical, zone, light, price, availability,street,city]

      csvfile_writer.writerow(csv_line)
csvfile.close()
```

`plant_catalog.csv`(output file):

```
common,botanical,zone,light,price,availability,street,city
Bloodroot,Sanguinaria canadensis,4,Mostly Shady,$2.44,031599,1,toronto
Columbine,Aquilegia canadensis,3,Mostly Shady,$9.37,030699,2,montreal
```